# How can I save the results of every loop in a for-loop with two counters in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I have my Code like this:

```
a=logical ([1]);

  b=logical (      [ 1     1     0
                     1     1     1
                     0     1     1]);

  c=logical (      [ 1     0     0     0
                     0     1     1     0
                     0     1     1     1
                     0     0     1     1]);

  d=logical (      [ 1     1     1
                     1     1     1
                     1     1     1]);
  E={   a
        b
        c
        d};

   for i= 1:numel(E)
    for j=1:numel(E{i}(:,1))
     a=numel(find(E{i}(j,:)))<2
      end
   end
```

i use the For-loop to check out, if the number digit "1" in each row of E is smaller as 2.
 My problem is : With the for-loop I always receive the result "a" as the result of the last loop. like this:

```
a =

         1


    a =

         0


    a =

         0


    a =

         0


    a =

         1


    a =

         0


    a =

         0


    a =

         0


    a =

         0


    a =

         0


    a =

         0
```

But I want to save the value of "a" in every loop (here 11 rows means 11 loops) in a vector. Like this:

```
a = [1
       0
       0
       0
       1
       0
       0
       0
       0
       0
       0]
```

Or clearly, I want to do these steps to E :

1.If a cell of E contains only  one elment (1 x 1) (here it is E(1) ), do nothing to it

2.Else , check it out, if the number of the digit "1" in each row of each cell in E is smaller as 2

so that in the end I have a result like this:

```
 a = [   0
         0
         0
         0
         1
         0
         0
         0
         0
         0
         0]
```

thanks for your help in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about skipping the loops and do

```
C = cellfun(@(x) sum(x,2)<2, E, 'UniformOutput', false);
a = cat(1, C{:})
```

Running Dan's loop and my `cellfun` for the `E` you give, 1000 times, results in

```
Elapsed time is 0.113762 seconds.  % loop, and 
Elapsed time is 0.234935 seconds.  % cellfun on small E
```

Running both solutions 1000 times on

```
E = repmat(E, 1e2,1);
```

gives

```
Elapsed time is 9.740406 seconds. % loop, and
Elapsed time is 2.538942 seconds. % cellfun on Large E
```

without pre-allocation of `a`, and

```
Elapsed time is 8.301579 seconds. % loop, and
Elapsed time is 2.538762 seconds. % cellfun on Large E
```

*with* pre-allocation of `a`.

So, if you have to do this often:

- if your data set is always small, use a loop
- if your data set is always large, use `cellfun`.

If you have to do this only a few times;

- use `cellfun` and don't worry so much about [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
   for i= 1:numel(E)
     for j=1:numel(E{i}(:,1))
       a(i, j) = numel(find(E{i}(j,:)))<2
     end
   end
```